# Socket 775 - 1156 cooler compatibility

Tags: cooling

I bought a new mobo with Socket 1156 (Asus P7P55D PRO). Previously I had a mobo with Socket 775 and CPU cooler AC Freezer 7 Pro. However, I'm not able to fit the cooler to the new mobo eventhough the mounting holes look to be at the same positions. I've seen a few coolers which support both sockets. Are these platforms "cooler mounting" compatible, or the cooler really have to support both sockets explicitely?

Comment: Have you tried a different orientation of the cooler? Also, I have had problems with this stock fastening system, where it simply doesn't want to attach more than 3 or 4 legs at a time. If you look through Newegg processor reviews, you'll find lots of hate on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a motherboard with both 1156 and 775 holes for a cpu cooler.  There are slight differences between the two.  You might be able to get the 775 to work with the 1156 but at the risk of maybe breaking something... including your knuckles :-)  I would suggest looking for a socket adapter so that your fitting things correctly.  I found a few [here](http://www.frozencpu.com/cat/l3/g48/c371/s441/list/p1/CPU_Heatsinks-CPU_Heatsinks_-_Misc-Socket_Adapters-Page1.html).

Answer (score 0):

What problem do you face when trying to fit the cooler?

You say the mounting holes are in the correct position, so what is stopping it from fitting?

---

According to [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835186134) your cooler should support i7 and i5 processors, which are socket LGA 1156;

> Compatible with Intel Core i7 and Core i5, as well as AMD sockets

Comment: I can't just fasten all the "legs". Unfortunately it's all covered by the board components so I'm not sure what's wrong. Probably the shape of the socket and cooler don't match. 
Problem is, that I have "the old" Freezer 7 not rev. 2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to answer this, but I had the EXACT same issue (same board, same cooler). I remember that I also had an issue getting it onto my socket 775 MB. In this case I kept trying and after some bloody hands managed it ... I got one diagonal set to go in at the same time, and then the other followed - I was scared that I had broken something, but it's working fine (so much better than the rubbish stock cooler!). Running at stock speeds the CPU (i7) sits about 33 C

Answer (score 0):

I have the AC Freezer Pro 7 Rev 2.  I don't know how much different it is from the original but I do remember having some trouble with the push pins.  After a few tries, I found that you can do it like this.

1. Insert all pins ever-so-slightly into each hole.
2. Start at one pin and push it in a tiny bit
3. Alternate to the opposite diagonal pin, push it in a tiny bit
4. Keep doing this until you can't push them any further without applying a larger amount of force.  At this point, you should be able to use needlenose pliers to grab the pin and push down.  It should pop right in.  The last pin will be the hardest but it *will* go in with the right amount of force.